# Hessian matrix, how to combine Ixx & Iyy together?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, detection, sobel, hessian-matrix

"Before extracting the lines, you need to detect potential points on them. Apply a Gaussian filter first and use the Sobel filters as derivative operators. Threshold the determinant of the Hessian and then apply non-maximum suppression in 3 × 3 neighborhoods. Ignore pixels for which any of the filters falls even partially out of the image boundaries."

I understand to gaussian an image first to eliminate noise, then take twice with Sobel_x and Sobel_y, respectively, which became Ixx and Iyy in Hessian that would show horizontal line and vertical line in image.But how am I suppose to get Ixxyy? But how could I combine these two image together to make Ixxyy as the right bottom in Hessian matrix?

Answer (score 1):

The two off-diagonal elements of the Hessian matrix are `d^2/dxdy`. That is, they are the first derivative along y applied to the first derivative along x.

If the top-left element is obtained by `Sobel_x( Sobel_x( image ))`, and the bottom-right element is `Sobel_y( Sobel_y( image ))`, then the two other elements are both `Sobel_y( Sobel_x( image ))` or, equivalently, `Sobel_x( Sobel_y( image ))` (note that these two should be identical).

Do take into account that negative values are important here, and  you should thus be careful to compute the Sobel filter in a way that preserves those negative values—don't store them in an unsigned integer array!